# Drupal 7 select query with joins on entity_id

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am trying to leftjoin off of the entity_id, but just receiving a error without details.

Is there a trick to leftjoin off of the entity_id in Drupal?

```
$query = db_query('SELECT COUNT(n.field_feed_vehicle_code_value) FROM {field_data_field_feed_vehicle_code} n LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_feed_vehicle_date_used} du ON n.entity_id = du.entity_id WHERE n.field_feed_vehicle_code_value = :utilization AND du.field_feed_vehicle_date_used = :utilization_date', array(':utilization' =>  $fieldVehicleCode, ':utilization_date' =>  $fieldDVIRDate))->fetchField();
```

I found other questions talking about leftjoins, but nothing really on entity_id. I also found this [Drupal 7 select query with joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574133/drupal-7-select-query-with-joins) but this solution did not work either.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_feed_vehicle_code', 'vc', 'n.nid =   vc.entity_id');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_feed_vehicle_date_used', 'du', 'n.nid = du.entity_id');
$query
->fields('n', array('nid'))
->fields('vc.field_feed_vehicle_code_value', $fieldVehicleCode , '=')
->fields('du.field_feed_vehicle_date_used', $fieldDVIRDate , '=')
->condition('type', 'dvir_utilization_feed')
->condition('status', 1)
->execute();
$num = $query->rowCount();
```

Comment: what sort of error without details?

Comment: Getting a 502 when I visit the page, but all others load fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to use

```
->condition('vc.field_feed_vehicle_code_value', $fieldVehicleCode , '=')
->condition('du.field_feed_vehicle_date_used', $fieldDVIRDate , '=')
```

as that is not the correct syntax for `->fields`

Comment: Here is what I am trying:
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->leftJoin('field_data_field_feed_vehicle_code', 'vc', 'n.nid =   vc.entity_id')
      ->leftJoin('field_data_field_feed_vehicle_date_used', 'du', 'n.nid = du.entity_id')
      ->fields('n', array('nid'))
      ->condition('vc.field_feed_vehicle_code_value', $fieldVehicleCode , '=')
      ->condition('du.field_feed_vehicle_date_used', $fieldDVIRDate , '=')
      ->condition('n.type', 'dvir_utilization_feed' , '=')
      ->execute();
$num = $query->rowCount();

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having the wrong field name and had to do db_query, although I would have preferred db_select.

```
$query = db_query('SELECT COUNT(vc.field_feed_vehicle_code_value)
                                  FROM {node} n 
                                  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_feed_vehicle_code} vc ON n.nid = vc.entity_id
                                  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_feed_vehicle_date_used} du ON n.nid = du.entity_id
                                  WHERE vc.field_feed_vehicle_code_value = :utilization 
                                     AND du.field_feed_vehicle_date_used_value = :utilization_date', 
                                  array(':utilization' =>  $fieldVehicleCode, ':utilization_date' =>  $fieldDVIRDate))->fetchField();


            $utilization = $query;
```